# Implementing LRU in mips

Tags: algorithm, assembly, mips

How LRU can be implemented in MIPS? The procedures that are used take in a lot of initialisations and the requirement of registers is quite high when trying to implement LRU with other functions like sort and other programs that use more variables. How can this issue be addressed?

Comment: Are you talking hardware or software? I assume LRU stands for "least recently used"? And this is a LRU _cache_? What type of objects is being stored, how are they being indexed, etc? More information and context please.

Comment: How do "other functions and programs" enter the picture? And what `registers` are you talking about - GP? That said, part of VM page replacement would be at interrupt time, in kernel mode, say TLB miss or TLB entry not valid, with bookkeeping at timer interrupt/process switch time (the TLB entries had a PID field from the start).

Answer (score 3):

Very few VM implementations actually use LRU, because of the cost. Instead they tend to use NRU (Not Recently Used) as an approximation. Associate each mapped in page with a bit which is set when that page is used (read from or written to). Have a process that regularly works round the pages in a cyclical order clearing this bit. When you want to evict a page, chose one that does not have this bit set, and so has not been used since the last time the cyclical process got round to it. If you don't even have a hardware-supported "not recently used" bit emulate it by having the cyclical process (this is sometimes known as the clock algorithm) clear the valid bit of the page table and have the interrupt handler for accessing an invalid page set a bit to say the page was referenced before setting the page as valid and restarting the instruction that trapped.

See e.g. http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~tom/Slides/caching2.pptx especially slide 19

Comment: And a valid bit was almost all VM page replacement hardware support that met my eye opening the (R2000) MIPS RISC Architecture handbook, with `tlbwr` (write (pseudo, see _Random_ register) random TLB entry, with the lower eight(h) of entries excluded) the rest of it.

Comment: A valid bit was all I could see with a quick web-search, but for all I know there are extended versions of MIPS out there with more support.